# Мультипоточный сервер

Tags: c#, .net, сервер, клиент-сервер, клиент

Доброго времени суток!
Имеется следующий код мультипоточного сервера и клиента:
Сервер:

```
namespace Server_Test
{
class Server
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Server serv = new Server();
    }
    private TcpListener listener { get; set; }
    private NetworkStream stream { get; set; }

    public Server()
    {
        listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.2"), 5052);
        listener.Start();
        new Thread(ListenForClients).Start();
    }

    private void ListenForClients()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            TcpClient client = this.listener.AcceptTcpClient();
            new Thread(HandleClient).Start(client);
        }
    }

    private void HandleClient(object tcpClient)
    {
        TcpClient client = (TcpClient)tcpClient;
        while (client.Connected)
        {

            Recieve(client);
        }
    }

    private void Recieve(TcpClient client)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
        Array.Clear(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        try
        {
            stream = client.GetStream();
            int bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, 12);
            if (bytesRead == 0) return;

            ushort id = BitConverter.ToUInt16(buffer, 0);
            long len = BitConverter.ToInt64(buffer, 2);
            ushort nameLen = BitConverter.ToUInt16(buffer, 10);
            stream.Read(buffer, 0, nameLen);
            string fileName = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, nameLen);

            if (id == 1)
            {
                using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create)))
                {
                    int recieved = 0;
                    while (recieved < len)
                    {
                        bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
                        recieved += bytesRead;
                        writer.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        Console.WriteLine("{0} bytes recieved.", recieved);
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine("File length: {0}", len);
                Console.WriteLine("File Name: {0}", fileName);
                Console.WriteLine("Recieved!");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(fileName);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            stream.Close();
            client.Close();
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            stream.Flush();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Клиент:

```
namespace ClientTest
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static TcpClient client;
        private static NetworkStream stream;

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string temp;
            client = new TcpClient("192.168.1.2", 5052);
            stream = client.GetStream();
            Console.WriteLine(client.SendBufferSize);
            //while ((temp = Console.ReadLine()) != "exit")
            {
                Send(temp);
            }
            */

            Thread one = new Thread(() => SendFile(new FileInfo(@"1.doc")));
            one.Start();
            Thread two = new Thread(() => SendFile(new FileInfo(@"2.docx")));
            two.Start();
            // Console.ReadKey(true);
        }

        public static void SendFile(FileInfo file)
        {
            stream = client.GetStream();
            byte[] id = BitConverter.GetBytes((ushort)1);
            byte[] size = BitConverter.GetBytes(file.Length);
            byte[] fileName = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(file.Name);
            byte[] fileNameLength = BitConverter.GetBytes((ushort)fileName.Length);
            byte[] fileInfo = new byte[12 + fileName.Length];

            id.CopyTo(fileInfo, 0);
            size.CopyTo(fileInfo, 2);
            fileNameLength.CopyTo(fileInfo, 10);
            fileName.CopyTo(fileInfo, 12);

            stream.Write(fileInfo, 0, fileInfo.Length); //Размер файла, имя

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 32];
            int count;

            long sended = 0;

            using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(file.FullName, FileMode.Open))
                while ((count = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    stream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
                    sended += count;
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} bytes sended.", sended);
                }
            stream.Flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Собственно, если с клиента передавать два файла, то сервер не может их корректно принять.
Таким образом, вопрос-что нужно поправить в текущем коде, чтобы передавать несколько файлов с клиента на сервер? 
Заранее спасибо за ответы и помощь.
UPD. Попробовал изменить SendFile следующим образом, не помогло.

```
public static void SendFile(FileInfo file)
    {
        TcpClient client;
        NetworkStream stream;
        client = new TcpClient("192.168.1.2", 5052);
        stream = client.GetStream();
        byte[] id = BitConverter.GetBytes((ushort)1);
        byte[] size = BitConverter.GetBytes(file.Length);
        byte[] fileName = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(file.Name);
        byte[] fileNameLength = BitConverter.GetBytes((ushort)fileName.Length);
        byte[] fileInfo = new byte[12 + fileName.Length];

        id.CopyTo(fileInfo, 0);
        size.CopyTo(fileInfo, 2);
        fileNameLength.CopyTo(fileInfo, 10);
        fileName.CopyTo(fileInfo, 12);

        stream.Write(fileInfo, 0, fileInfo.Length); //Размер файла, имя

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 32];
        int count;

        long sended = 0;

        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(file.FullName, FileMode.Open))
            while ((count = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                stream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
                sended += count;
                Console.WriteLine("{0} bytes sended.", sended);
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Сервер принимает файлы от клиента, считая что они идет последовательно. Клиент же пытается передать их одновременно - отсюда и каша.

Без сложных правил пультиплексирования одновременная запись в поток TCP невозможна. Каша будет получаться всегда.

Чтобы передать два файла с клиента, надо либо передать их последовательно - либо открыть свое соединение для каждого файла.

Comment: То есть в SendFile нужно открывать соединение?

Comment: Добавил к посту переделанный, но не работающий SendFile.

Comment: Проверьте, не использует ли сервер каких-нибудь ресурсов, разделенных между разными клиентами. Если использует - то зачем?